# Pyspark slower on my machine than my coworker's even though we have the same machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Coworker and I are running the exact same query yet my machine is significantly slower than his even though we have the same specifications. My machine takes almost twice as long to run the query on pyspark. Are there any ways to figure out if I'm missing a binary/jar?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your coworker edited the spark-env to give it more memory? Maybe there are *other proceses* **not** running on the other machine? If the query runs at all, you are not missing libraries

Comment: @cricket_007 our spark-env are exactly the same and the proccesses running roughly take the same amount of CPU/RAM usage.

Comment: Maybe there is some caching involved? Network overhead? Your disk or memory sectors are bad... There's not a straightforward answer here that is just related to a single machine.

Comment: @cricket_007 maybe i'll try writing locally. I just wanted to rule out any missing binaries before anything else.

Comment: If you're code isn't already local, I'm not sure I understand how you're judging speed. If you're submitting to a remote cluster, then there's additional resource constraints on those machines